# How to set textfield value which automatically insert decimal values with $ format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my app i have one textbox.now when click on textbox numeric keypad will open.Now my question how to code which automatically insert decimal values with $ fromat.

For an example user type `10` the result is `$.10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField         
{
    NSString *temp = textField.text;
    textField.text = @"$.%@",temp; 
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this method automatically called or we have to give link?

Comment: you just need to set delegate of UITextField to current view controller

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField         
{
     textField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$.%d",[[textField text] intValue] ];
     return YES;
}
```